# Vue 3 with Vue Router: Router links have correct Vue param but not reflected in HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

My single page app retrieves organization data from an Express endpoint and lists the different organizations available to the logged in user account.

`getUser` is a vuex getter. The list of organizations prints fine. The code below displays the organization slug (org.slug) as a parameter on the router-link for each organization when I check in the Vue inspector plugin.

But the compiled html (dev mode) fails to reflect the individual slug parameter. All the links display the same `a href="..."` element, pointing to the first organization slug in the array, at index 0.

It's only the org.slug value that is repeated in the v-for loop/list. The org.name and org.id are correct.

```
<li v-for="org in getUser.organizations" :key="org.id">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'dashboard', params: org.slug }">
      {{ org.name }}
    </router-link>
</li>
```

In the Vue inspector:

```
props
    ariaCurrentValue:"page"
    custom:false
    to:Object
      name:"dashboard"
      params:"my-organization-0" // this changes to -1, -2, etc depending on the list item in the list
```

Vue Router:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    meta: { publicRoute: true }
  },
  {
    path: '/:slug/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */'../views/Dashboard.vue')
  },
  {
    ...etc.
  }
]
```

Do any of you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: could you share the router definition?

Comment: Could you try `params: { slug: org.slug }` in router-link?

Comment: Awesome @PrerakSola. That was it. I had completely missed that my variable wasn't an object already. Thanks! Make it an answer and I'll select it, if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a variable to a route, you need to provide its value in `params` object. So it would be like:

`:to="{ name: 'dashboard', params: { slug: org.slug } }">`

Reference: [API Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props)